# Angular CLI - missing SASS Import

Tags: sass, angular-cli, uswds

I'm working on a project that is using the the [U.S. Web Design Standards](https://standards.usa.gov/) framework and I have imported all the `SASS` files into my `main.scss` file:

```
@import "bourbon/bourbon";

@import "abstracts/variables";

// This imports all the required files 
@import "../vendor_files/uswds/src/stylesheets/uswds";
```

But I'm noticing that some of the grid styles are missing when I run my local server. Just as a test I did a sass compile via my terminal and was able to find the associated grid styles. I can provide additional information if needed.

#### Versions

```
@angular/cli: 1.6.0
node: 8.8.1
os: darwin x64
@angular/animations: 4.4.6
@angular/common: 4.4.6
@angular/compiler: 4.4.6
@angular/core: 4.4.6
@angular/forms: 4.4.6
@angular/http: 4.4.6
@angular/platform-browser: 4.4.6
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.4.6
@angular/router: 4.4.6
@angular/cli: 1.6.0
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.6
@angular/language-service: 4.4.6
typescript: 2.3.4
```

#### Repro steps

My sample [repo](https://github.com/herrjosua/uswds-sass-angular-cli)

1. `npm install`
2. `npm start`

#### Observed behavior

[image: screen shot 2017-12-07 at 08 59 40]

Note the alignment of the copy `A tagline highlights your approach` compared to the Desired behavior below.

#### Desired behavior

I'm expecting the page to look like the one on the [USWDS documentation](https://standards.usa.gov/page-templates/landing/).

[image: screen shot 2017-12-07 at 11 23 03]

Answer (score 0):

With the help of a co-worker I was finally able to resolve the issue. I was missing the `bourbon-neat` package. Once I installed and added to my `scss` file the issue was resolved.